# Need help on Mongoid date range query

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, mongodb-query

I need a help on `mongoid` date range query.

I am trying to query events that spans over certain date range.

The `event` collection has two fields in the database `start_date` and `end_date`.

What would be the query to, for example, find events that occur between *04-18-2015 to 04-28-2015*?

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful to you :

```
db.collectionName.find({
"start_date": { $lt: endDate }, // add end date here
"end_date": { $gt: startDate } // add start date here
});
```